# JavaScript Alert Displaying Peculiar Value

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following text input field (StartDate) in my form:

```
<form id="Form1" name="form" runat="server" onsubmit="return formValidate(this)">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td class="label">
               Start Date:
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="StartDate" maxlength="10" />
          </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

When I type in a value, like "03/26/2017," and alert the StartDate's value, I receive an odd value.

Here is the alert:

```
function formValidate(formObj)
{
    alert(formObj.elements.item('StartDate').value);
}
```

[image: Alert Screenshot]

I am running this in Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: somehow, i don't think we're seeing all the code in-play here...

Comment: Looks like base64, something is happening outside the context of the code you have provided ... (Also FYI there is `<input type="date" ..`)

Comment: This is just a snippet of a much larger piece of code. The form is indeed encapsulated in a <td> as well.

Comment: Does not happen here: https://jsfiddle.net/quar820j/

Comment: @OmnusRuthius I believe Alon's point is that there is no way that you can have `<form><td>` without invalidating your HTML. The parent of a `<td>` cannot be a `<form>`.

Comment: You're right, that was a mistype on my part. My mistake. Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @AlexK. I changed it to date but still getting the strange value.

Comment: Please show us how do you get the `formObj` variable?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I have updated the code showing how I pass the formObj variable to the JavaScript alert.

Comment: As @MatteoTassinari has shown, it is working in isolation. Note you are using a very old version of Chrome (mine is on 57). I doubt that's affecting anything. Note that it appears as though you're using ASP.NET (`runat="server"`). I'm not sure that would affect anything, but could be a factor.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius still working on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quar820j/1/

Comment: I've never used either of these methods, but is there any reason why you'd want to use item() instead of namedItem()? Could the older version of chrome have some bug in the item method?

Comment: Thanks iceman, changing it to namedItem actually works. Also, formObj.elements["StartDate"].value works just as well.

@MatteoTassinari I appreciate the help, but the fiddles are just showing me what I expect my own code to accomplish. I know what I need it to do, the question is why I am seeing it with the code that I provided. The answer turned out to be the usage of ".item", which was in legacy code and inherited by myself to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
formObj.elements.item('StartDate').value
```

needed to be changed to

```
formObj.elements["StartDate"].value
```

My guess is the browser version I'm using is having trouble with the ".item" usage. Changing it as reflected above seems to fix the issue.